# C++ Function Coding

Tags: c++, function

I just started learning functions.  I'm trying to write this code with using a function to have a user input the names.  I can't figure out what the argument should be.  I thought I could put in getName(i.name) passing an array into it, but I'm doing it wrong.  What should the correct parameter be?

```
void getName(Horse &);  //function prototype
struct Horse
{
    string name;
}
array<Horse, horseCount> Horses;
for (Horse &i : Horses)
{
    getName(i.name);
}
void getName(Horse &Nag)
{
    cout << "Enter a horse's name: ";
    getline(cin, Nag.name);
}
```

Comment: Just plain `getName(i)`

Comment: `for (Horse &i : Horses)` cannot occur outside of a function as you have it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a `std::string` to `getName()` when it actually expects `Horse&`.

You must call it as `getname(i)` to actually pass the `Horse` object.

Answer (score 0):

The correct parameter would be an object of type `Horse`. You can change your code to this. The below code seems to be just a snippet, I'm assuming it's part of a function body that you've defined.

`i.name` in this case is of type `std::string`, but your prototype of `getName` takes a `Horse` object, not a string.

```
for (Horse &i : Horses)
{
    getName(i);
}

void getName(Horse &Nag)
{
    cout << "Enter a horse's name: ";
    getline(cin, Nag.name);
}
```